# Magento: Add a multi-select attribute to categories with existing source?

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

I have an existing 'brand' select-attribute.
Is there a way to add a multiple-select field to categories with values from this attribute (Perhaps something similar to how I'd add a Yes/No attribute to categories)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) of how you can create a product attribute with custom options. It works the same for categories.

Just change this:

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'provider', array(
```

to this:

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'provider', array(
```

The main idea is to give the attribute a custom source that is a model with a method that returns all the options.

TO get all the options of brand attribute, do this:

```
$options = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand')->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: I'm guessing I can't have them share a source? i.e, adding options to one will add them to the other..?

Comment: Yes. If you follow whar the tutorial dwscribes combined with what i've said then adding one option fpr product brand will add one for the custom category attribute